# addEventListener() Not Working - can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Wrote a super basic script to try out `addEventListener` and it's not working ...

Why?

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

        <script>

            function validateMe(){

                document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",validateForm); 

                function validateForm(){
                    alert("Wheeeeee!");
                }

                window.addEventListener("load",validateMe);

            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form name="" id="" action="" onsubmit="return validateMe">
                First Name: <input type="input" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
                <br /><br />
                Last Name: <input type="input" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
                <br /><br />
                Email Address: <input type="input" name="email" id="email" />
                <br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Validate" id="button1" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, just never gets called. `window.addEventListener("load",validateMe);` is _inside_ `validateMe()`, so it's sort of a catch-22.

Comment: Also, `onsubmit="return validateMe"` isn't going to call `validateMe`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, duh! Thank you for pointing that out! Should have noticed that! Also, is this the "better" way to call it as opposed to `onsubmit` in form?

Comment: @Phil, hey, yeah, wrote that earlier and forgot to take it out. Think that `addEventListener` is better way to go about this, yes?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, hey, also, since you pointed out the obvious which helped with this, make it an answer if you want credit =)

Comment: @user273072545345 if by "better" you mean it addresses the best practice of separating concerns, then yes.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, yeah, I meant that. `onsubmit` is considered "outdated" yes?

Comment: Not outdated, just bad practice. event attributes aren't actually deprecated officially, so until that occurs, it will not be considered "outdated."

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, okay dokey. thank you. reminder, please make your comment an answer if you want credit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to add the function from within the function itself. The function will not get executed, therefore it will not be added. Try moving the addEventListener statement outside of the function block. Or, make the function anonymous and declare it inside the addEventListener call.

Edit: I see now it does get executed on submit. But the load phase has already passed so adding it at that point won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **validateForm()**. You have a function within the function which isn't being called anywhere.

```
        function validateMe(){

            document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",validateForm); 


                alert("Wheeeeee!");


            window.addEventListener("load",validateMe);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from your case, You may want to use `addEventListener()` instead of in-line event usage.

You could remove in-line event `onsubmit="return validateMe"` from the form DOM, then your `window.addEventListener("load",validateMe)` needs to be called out of its function:

```
function validateMe(){  
  document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",validateForm); 
  function validateForm(){
    alert("Wheeeeee!");
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load", validateMe);
```

[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/87c7przk/)